Why is $f(x)=c+\int_{x_0}^x g(y) \mathrm{d} y$ extendable to the boundary for $f, g \in L_{1, \mathrm{loc}}(a, b)$?
I am reading the following set of notes about sobolev spaces: https://www.mat.tuhh.de/veranstaltungen/isem18/pdf/Lecture04.pdf
There are two claims presented :
Proposition. Let $-\infty \leqslant a<x_0<b \leqslant \infty, f, g \in L_{1, \mathrm{loc}}(a, b)$. Then $f^{\prime}=g$ in the distributional sense if and only if there exists $c \in \mathbb{K}$ such that
$$
f(x)=c+\int_{x_0}^x g(y) \mathrm{d} y \quad(\text { a.e. } x \in(a, b)) .
$$
Theorem. Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Then every $f \in H^1(a, b)$ possesses a representative in $C[a, b]$, and the inclusion $H^1(a, b) \subseteq C[a, b]$ thus defined is continuous.
In the proof of the second theorem above, the author claims that "the first proposition immediately implies that every function $f \in H^1(a, b)$ has a continuous representative which also can be extended continuously to $[a, b]$."
I believe continuity is just the Lebesgue version of the fundamental theorem of calculus (Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem), but I am not sure why we can extend it to the endpoints. Every continuous function is locally integrable, but it can explode if we include the endpoints.

You can view it abstractly as a corollary of Sobolev embedding, or simply by Cauchy-Schwarz, using the fact that $g\in L^2((a,b))$ and $a,b$ are finite: for all $x,y\in (a,b)$, we have
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\int_x^yg(t)\,dt\right|\leq \|g\|_{L^2((a,b))}\cdot |x-y|^{1/2}.
\end{align}
So, $f$ is Holder-continuous of degree $\frac{1}{2}$, so in particular it is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, and hence has a continuous extension to the boundary (and so this Holder-bound extends to the boundary as well, so the inequality holds for all $x,y\in [a,b]$, once we replace $f$ with its continuous extension $\widetilde{f}:[a,b]\to\Bbb{C}$).
If instead you had the hypothesis $g\in L^p((a,b))$ for some $1<p\leq\infty$, then applying Holder’s inequality proves that $f$ is Holder-continuous of degree $1-\frac{1}{p}$, and so again, it extends continuously to $[a,b]$.

Thank you for the clear explanation!
